# UITextField not returning anything

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitextfield

I have a TextField that is not returning anything. Not even a null.

In cellForRowAtIndexPath I have:

```
UsernameTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"UsernameTableViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.username.delegate = self;
return cell;
```

Then in didSelectRowAtIndexPath I have:

```
UsernameTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"UsernameTableViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

But, whenever I try to log cell.username.text, I get nothing. When I log cell.username I get this:

```
Cell <UITextField: 0x9ce6650; frame = (0 0; 320 74); text = ''; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x9cc7e00>; layer = <CALayer: 0x9cde170>>
```

Some background info: I have an IBOutlet in a TableViewCell to a UITextField. I'm trying to get it's data within a TableViewController. Basically, I have a UITextField within a TableViewCell, and I'm trying to get what the user types into that to TextField and send it to Parse in TableViewController.

Comment: I'd give about 4:1 odds that you're not addressing the right cell.

Comment: Once the user enters text inside of the TextView, are you calling Reload Data (called after editing ends in the text view)? If not, the cells haven't been updated to reflect the change.

Comment: @pnavk I don't really know what you mean by that.

Comment: @HotLicks What do you mean by that? I'm sure that the username field is in the usernametableviewcell.

Comment: How many UserNameTableViewCell objects are there?  This is a "table view" after all, and a "table view" consists of multiple identical cells.  Which one are you trying to get a name out of?

Comment: @HotLicks There is one object within UserNameTableViewCell which is username. There is also a PasswordTableViewCell which has an object of password.

Comment: And there's only one UserNameTableViewCell in your table view???

Comment: Hint:  Put an NSLog in cellForRowAtIndexPath and see when it's called relative to your other operations.

Comment: Yes @HotLicks it's the only one named that

Comment: (I strongly suspect that this app is totally mucked up, and you need to go back and study up on table views a bit more, then start over fresh.  You're never going to get this to work since you don't understand what you're doing.)

Comment: And I didn't ask if there was more than one thing named "UserNameTableViewCell", I asked how many *instances* there are of that *class*.  I suspect you don't quite understand the difference between *class* and *instance*.

Comment: Putting a log there wouldn't do anything because it does it when the view loads, and it's empty.

Comment: @HotLicks Can I just send you the project so you can see what's wrong?

Comment: I know what's wrong, but you aren't listening.

Comment: @HotLicks I just don't understand what you're telling me

Comment: Find a book that explains "objects".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had done something Similar to this.. I had a textfield in within tableViewCell, I had made within a Custom Cell and assigned it as an IBoutlet t theta CustomCell's CLass and then did something Like this..

You need to maintain an array as "textFieldValueArray" which would contain all the values of the textfield when edited or not what I had done was create an array with empty string's (such as "" at start when viewLoads), and had inserted the string in the array so that it equals the number of  tableView cells Count, and then,

In -cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
 (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{


 cell.userName.delegate=self;

cell.userName.text=[textFieldValueArray objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];
    [cell.userName addTarget:self action:@selector(usernameEdited:event:)   forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingDidEnd];



}
```

and then in the textField method:

```
-(IBAction)usernameEdited:(UITextField*)textField event:(UIEvent*)event{

    NSString *str=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",textField.text];

    CGPoint location = [self.tableView convertPoint:textField.frame.origin fromView:textField.superview];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:location];

    [self.tableArray setObject: str atIndexedSubscript:indexPath.row];

    [self.tableView reloadData];

}
```

Comment: Wait, where'd you get self.tableView?

Comment: Self.tableView is your table view which you have declared as a property

Comment: Oh, I hadn't done that yet. Strong & nonatomic? And where do I setup the array?

Comment: yes, you should make your table view an IBoutlet from your StoryBoard

Comment: For some reason, it's not letting me create an outlet. Can we talk over email?

Comment: Do you know how to do "File>Write All Class Files" and "File>Read All Class Files" in Xcode 5?

Comment: What do you want to write or read over here and sure my emails geet.dwd@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

Try `UsernameTableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];` in your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method.

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work. Something about incompatibility.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following. If you were getting a warning with Undo's answer, casting it should fix the warning.

```
UsernameTableViewCell *cell = (UsernameTableViewCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
NSLog(@"%@", cell.username);
```

Comment: Whenever I do that, I get an error. It says `[UITableViewCell username]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9a86c50`

Comment: It looks like your cells aren't actually subclassed then, the system thinks they're `UITableViewCell`s. Make sure in Interface Builder that your cell's class is set to `UsernameTableViewCell`.

Comment: Yes, it is set up like that in interface builder.

Comment: Hmm. Are you able to access your cell's text field anywhere else? You said that when you logged one of the fields you got output, which implies that the object exists.

Comment: I don't how to test it anywhere else.

Comment: Where/how did you get that log output?

Comment: If you're getting UITableViewCell from cellForRowAtIndexPath, and you don't have your cell object as a subview of the UITableViewCell, then you're kinda mucked up.

Comment: Within TableViewController in didSelectRowAtIndex.